# Git pull request (Github) - where does it merge?

Tags: git, github, branch, pull-request

If I fork repo `Foobar`'s master branch and make some edits and then submit a pull request that is approved, my changes get pulled into `Foobar`'s master branch.  What if I fork `Foobar`'s master branch but when I make a pull request I want the changes to be pulled into branch `xyzzy` rather than branch `master`.  How does Github decide which branch to merge the pull request into?  Do I need to make a `xyzzy` branch on my forked repo and then make a pull request from there?  Or is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open a pull request you can choose which you want your changes to be merged into.

Where you see `Foobar:master ... YourRepo:master` there is a `Edit` button on the far right which will then allow you to choose a different base branch - see below.

[image]